# Easy UI implementations for Rails, coming from PHP

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I have developed web applications for WordPress and I love it. It has themes that made navigation so simple and intuitive. If I had to code them in a framework it might take days. On top of that, I make use of custom themes and I write my own scripts so that it could suit my needs. Therefore, simple posts are not sufficient and I tend to 'hack' it by piggiebacking postmeta to the post. This will suit almost every type of tables I need. Of course, not the most efficient way.

My friend told me that ruby on Rails is a much better practise to do the above. But I'm afraid that the learning cuve is too steep. Moreover, I need to redesign my navigation UI for Rails, which might add on alot to production time. WordPress really have stunning themes. And I also need to code up user-authentication on Rails, whereas WordPress has user table that I could just use.

Any thoughts on this? What are alternatives to create beautiful themes on Rails. This is currently holding me back from moving to Rails.

Comment: Yeah, rails has none of that. There are some blog engines, but they all are a far cry from wordpress. You will likely find yourself coding most of the stuff you now take for granted.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sigh:/ that's not good to hear.

Comment: Also, running a rails app is a bit more complicated than running a php app. You can't just SCP a couple of files and expect the app to pick them up. That's why there is no rich theme customization stuff (a la wordpress, where you can even edit themes online)

Comment: I mean, ruby/rails is beautiful, if you want to build something from scratch. There is a gem for every need. But there's no wordpress. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev are you a rails developer? How would you suggest to improve UI on rails? I don't mind clean flat design. It's quite simple to implement that too.

Comment: What do you mean, improve? There's [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), for example.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev oh, can't install gems to make UI implementation simpler?

Comment: There's a gem that bundles bootstrap :)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Maybe I'll try to play around with Rails a little to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big difference: Wordpress is a CMS whereas Rails is an App Framework which you could use to implement a CMS. There would be a lot of from scratch code you'd have to write to get to where Wordpress is.

If you like going the from scratch route there are a bunch of Gems that help out with common things like user authentication (Devise), using markdown in posts (Redcarpet), Front end frameworks (Bootstrap, Foundation which have their own themes that are easy to add) and many others.

There are also quite a few [CMSs written in Rails](http://codecall.net/2014/02/10/best-ruby-on-rails-content-management-systems-cms/).

But of course there would be the learning curve of Ruby, rails, and then learn the structure of the CMS. You really have to evaluate your requirements and decide what suits you best for the work you're doing.

If Wordpress does everything you need then you don't need to step to a lower level. A PHP equivalent to Rails might be CakePHP, Codeigniter, but again, those are App Frameworks and don't have any of the pre built bells and whistles as any CMS.